# Django models in Many2Many relationship: filter by a group of member

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have these models:

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Engineer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    skill = models.ManyToManyField(Skill)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)


class City(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

I have 2 questions, please spare your time to help me. Thank you :)

1) I would like to filter Engineer by a group of skills. 
Let's say I need to filter engineers, who have these skills ['HTML', 'python', 'CSS']. How can I do that?

2) I would like to filter Engineer by a group of skills **AND** in a specific area. 
Let's say I need to filter engineers, who have these skills ['HTML', 'python', 'CSS'] **AND** this engineer must live in Anaheim. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read *[queries that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)* part of the docs. Basically querying is done in the same kinda syntax you do *ForeignKey* lookups. (In case you don't use [m2m through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) though)

Also you don't have any relation between an *Engineer* and a *City*, If you want to be able to answer to queries like your second question, you need to add a *ForeignKey*, from *Engineer* to *City*.

1.

```
skills = Skill.objects.filter(name__in=['HTML', 'Python', 'Css'])
engineers = Engineer.objects.filter(skill__in=skills)
```

2.

```
city = City.objects.get(name='Anaheim')
engineers = Engineer.objects.filter(skill__in=skills, city=city) # Considering you put a ForeignKey from Engineer to City
```